# Loading content the normal way vs through ajax (json)

Tags: html, ajax, seo

I now have most of the pages within my cart (search results, category data, product data, cart, etc) loaded via ajax (json). I'm now thinking to load up the main category's on the home page through ajax (json) as well to further boost up the speed. This would for example look something like the following:

```
<b>Categories</b><br />
<a href="#A/1234">Category A</a> <br />
<a href="#A/5678">Category B</a>

<noscript>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/1234/category A/">Category A</a> <br />
<a href="http://www.domain.com/5678/category B/">Category B</a>
</noscript>
```

instead of just:

```
<b>Categories</b><br />
<a href="http://www.domain.com/1234/category A/">Category A</a> <br />
<a href="http://www.domain.com/5678/category B/">Category B</a>
```

However would it be right to load these categories through ajax (json) as well? I tend to look how major websites are doing it and they're almost always loading up content not through ajax (json) but rather the normal (static) way. Even Stackoverflow does this. I only see gmail being 100% ajax but that's more like an app. 
And if I would this, would it be better to load up the category links dynamically through ajax (json) on load-up of the homepage as well to prevent search engines seeing double links (the ajax links and the noscript links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fromt the UX if your website has lots of content (images, links, text etc) I think that it would be great to use AJAX. Chained AJAX functions can reveal the content the way you like and also you can navigate your user through your desired point of view.

Furthermore using AJAX you will reduce the time your website loads. Also, as I have read search engines can crawl AJAX as well. For SEO with AJAX try reading this small guide
http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-for-ajax/19138/

Comment: For some reason I can't tag you.... :S Thanks for the advice, i'll probably do it. In terms of seo I actually found this article to be very interesting. http://nickjohnson.com/b/how-to-make-ajax-search-engine-friendly-seo It does basically the same as i was thinking to do but then instead of jquery's onclick event it does it a bit differently.